# Why I don't get the wanted width of tcbox?

Tags: header-footer, tcolorbox

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\tcbox[colback=Khaki1!25!white,colframe=DarkGoldenrod2!75!black,arc=1mm,width=5cm]{\textit{\emph{\thepage}}}}


\begin{document}

abc

\end{document}
```

The result at the bottom of the page is:
[image]

Why the box is not 5cm long?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the capture mode, if you want the box not to fit to the contents:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\tcbox[capture=minipage,colback=Khaki1!25!white,colframe=DarkGoldenrod2!75!black,arc=1mm,width=5cm]{\textit{\emph{\thepage}}}}


\begin{document}

abc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My compliments. I was trying to read the manual :-)

Comment: When I tried to add shadow - it's not added, do you now why? Thank you!!

Comment: shadows need the enhanced skin.

Comment: Yes, I put `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` but still there is no shadow...

Comment: Works fine for me, `enhanced,drop shadow=blue,` gives a shadow.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, also for me!  Thank you :-)